# Convert the explicit formula $a_n=5n-42$ to a recursive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Convert the following explicit formula to a recursive formula.

$$a_n=5n-42, \text{where}\; n\geq0$$

Comment: What have you tried? Because this is not a homework site

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: This question is very similar to your previous question. Can you learn from that?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685382/convert-the-following-recursive-formula-to-an-explicit-formula).

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $a_0 = -42$ and $a_n = 5n-42 = 5(n-1)-42+5 = a_{n-1}+5\implies a_n = a_{n-1}+5$. Thus the recursive equation you are looking for is: $a_0 = -42, a_n = a_{n-1}+5, n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=5n - 42$$
Then:
$$a_{n+1} = 5(n+1) - 42 = 5n + 5 -42 = a_n + 5$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have $a_n = f(n)$, then to find a recursive formula, you can use:

$$a_{n+1}-a_n = f(n+1)-f(n)$$

Adding $a_n$ to both sides gives:

$$a_{n+1} = a_n + f(n+1) - f(n)$$

For this problem:

$$a_{n+1} = a_n + (5(n+1)-42) - (5n-42) = a_n+5$$